# Build failed to compile - Attempted import error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My attempt to build for production fails every time because of this error:

> Attempted import error: 'decrypt' is not exported from
> '../../../../util/security' (imported as 'decrypt').

This error only appears when I try to build for production (npm run build).

Here is the way I import my modules:

```
import {encrypt2, decrypt} from "../../../../util/security";
```

And how I export it :

```js
module.exports = {

    decrypt: function(encrypted_route) {
        encrypted_route = atob(encrypted_route);
        let [initialVector, salt, aes_route] = encrypted_route.split("::");
        let key = generateKey(salt);

        let cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
            ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(aes_route)
        });

        let unencrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            cipherParams,
            key,
            {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(initialVector)}
        );
        return unencrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    },

};
```

(The module decrypts my encrypted route)

I checked and the file is in the right place, moreover, in development mode it works as intended.

Comment: Have you tried exporting with `export ...` or `export default ...` rather than `module.exports`? What you try at the moment looks like mixing node.js style of exporting (`module.exports`) with es6 importing (`import ...`)

Comment: Nop, didn't try with `export ...`, I will give it a shot !

Comment: Aaah it's was my export solution that was causing the error, exporting every function like `export ...` fixed my problem ! Yeah module.exports was a bit messy to use ...

Comment: Will post this as an answer then.

Comment: Oh please do,  if you want, was about to make it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to replace Node.js style exports (`module.exports =` ) with ES6 exports (`export ...` or `export default ...` depending on how you want to import it).

The reason is that import/export styles have to be compatible and while there are scenarios where this could work, mixing the two styles in a React app is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your import to:

```js
import * as security from "../../../../util/security";
```

and use it like:

```js
security.decrypt(...)
```

Comment: Nop, the error remain the same : Attempted import error: 'decrypt' is not exported from '../../../../util/security' (imported as 'security').